# How can you define distance in QGIS Multiple ring buffer?

Tags: qgis, buffer

I am trying to create multiple buffers around point data. I need to crate buffers of 10 miles, but I cannot find a way to define this. I have tried using both the multiring buffer plugin and the multi-distance buffer plugin, but both of these are not producing the doughnut style rings, but instead just fill the map. I have limited the attribute table to the 10 ring and this still fills the table, so I can only assume the problem is with not being able to state I want miles. Is there a way to define the distances needed?

Comment: Is your data in WGS84? Check http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74996/need-projection-help-to-buffer-lines-in-qgis?rq=1 and related questions.

Comment: Yes, it is WGS84/UTM 15N

Comment: @GemmaDavies another great postgis example...!